# Sending a dm to my friend on discord via my account without opening discord in python

Tags: python, discord

I want to send a direct message to my friend on discord from my account without actually opening discord in python. I searched on the internet but everyone are using bots and servers. I tried using urllib and webbrowser modules but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You cannot write a program to send a DM from your personal Discord account, at least not by following the Discord rules. Allowing a program to login to a non-bot account is against ToS, and Discord is quite aggressive in enforcing this. If you want to do something automated, write a bot.

Comment: Silvio Mayolo, thanks for the information.